# Is it possible to configure intellisense for a Cython project?

Tags: c++, cython, intellisense

I downloaded a Cython project and its composition is as follows:

```
Project
├── build
├── include
├── setup.py
└── src
```

in which `src` and `include` folders contain some `.cpp` and `.h` files, respectively.

I can successfully build the Python wrapper with `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`. Since I'm new to `Cython`, I'm curious how developers write `C++` code for the `Cython` project with intellisense. Is it possible to generate some files, like `compile_command.json`, when conducting the compilation process for `Cython` code to configure the itellisense for `Clangd`?

Or, in a traditional way, configuring intellisense by compiling the `C++` project with `CMakeList`. After that, remove `CMakeList` when releasing the `Cython` project.